# Android Bluetooth Socket not created

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

My app is trying to connect with a Bluetooth module and Send/Receive data simultaneously. But sometimes the following error is thrown (it usually happens after a GC call):-

```
12-15 19:06:15.559: D/dalvikvm(22875): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3925K, 25% free 11400K/15096K, paused 28ms, total 28ms    
12-15 19:06:15.559: E/System(22875): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer 
12-15 19:06:15.559: E/System(22875): java.io.IOException: socket not created    
12-15 19:06:15.559: E/System(22875):    at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.shutdownInput(LocalSocketImpl.java:392)
12-15 19:06:15.559: E/System(22875):    at android.net.LocalSocket.shutdownInput(LocalSocket.java:206)
12-15 19:06:15.559: E/System(22875):    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.close(BluetoothSocket.java:462)
12-15 19:06:15.559: E/System(22875):    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.finalize(BluetoothSocket.java:229)
12-15 19:06:15.559: E/System(22875):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:187)
12-15 19:06:15.559: E/System(22875):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:170)
12-15 19:06:15.559: E/System(22875):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

This uncaught exception is thrown repeatedly for few number of times and as a result my app stop responding.

What can be the possible reasons for this error? I am trying to solve it but can't find the exact issue. Please help.

I am also attaching the code which I am using to connect with Bluetooth module. I am using an AsyncTask to do this..

```
    //global variable
    BluetoothSocket mBSocket;

    // inside doInBackground() function
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        try {
            for (BluetoothDevice bt : mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices()) {
                if (bt.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("MY_DEVICE_BT_NAME")) {
                    BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter
                            .getRemoteDevice(bt.getAddress());
                    mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery(); // We have named our
                                                            // device so
                                                            // cancel search
                    mBSocket = device
                            .createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(SPP_UUID);
                    if(!mBSocket.isConnected()) {
                        mBSocket.connect();
                    }
                    return mBSocket;
                }
            }
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } 
    } else
        return null;
```

Comment: Hey Paride, I almost forgot about this question, I am posting the modified code which I am using now to connect to my Bluetooth module. Tell me if that resolves your problem too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified the code to connect to my Bluetooth module, handled the exceptions properly, since then there isn't any such error I am facing as I have described in my question.

```
//global variable
BluetoothSocket mBSocket;

// inside doInBackground() function
mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
if(mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    try {
        for(BluetoothDevice bt: mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices()) {
            if(bt.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(params[0])) {
                BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(bt.getAddress());
                mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

                mBSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(SPP_UUID);
                mBSocket.connect();
                return mBSocket;
            }
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        if(mBSocket != null) {
            try {
                mBSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            mBSocket = null;
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
} 
return null;
```

Comment: Hi Androider, I would like to contact you in private as I can detail what I need. Is it possible?

Comment: could you give me a your email address?

Comment: ohhh.. sorry I wasn't aware how chat works here.. Here is my email: raivikrant1@gmail.com

Comment: This was all you changed? `if(!mBSocket.isConnected()) {
     mBSocket.connect();
    }`